# How to generate interfaces of models using openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I use openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 6.4.0 and it generates to me interfaces for resources (I use `configOptions` - `interfaceOnly`), but I am getting concrete classes of models.

How can I get interfaces for the models instead of concrete classes?

Comment: Please share your maven plugin configuration.  You are likely setting your options incorrectly.

Comment: @tbatch I'm getting interfaces for resources (the interfaceOnly option work correctly), but I want to get interfaces for models requests and responses instead concrete classes.

Comment: gotcha.  answer incoming.

Answer (score 2):

## How does openapi support polymorphism?

OpenAPI [supports polymorphism](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/) in multiple ways, by using either the `oneOf` of `anyOf` keywords.  According to the documentation:

> In your API, you can have request and responses that can be described by several alternative schemas.  In OpenAPI 3.0, to describe such a model, you can use the oneOf or anyOf keywords

The `oneOf` keyword says to make an object that contains either `A` or `B`.  This is the basic definition of an interface as well.

So, in order to get an interface to generate, we have to define the interface within our schema.  We can do this by creating our parent object using the `oneOf` keyword.  Take a look at this example:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.4
info:
  title: My-API
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: 'https://my.website.com'
paths:
  /employees:
    post:
      tags:
        - article
      summary: Add a new article to the store
      description: Get an Object
      operationId: getObject
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/EmployeeInfo'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
components:
  schemas:
    EmployeeInfo:
      description: general employee information
      type: object
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ManagementInfo'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/GruntInfo'
    GruntInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        phone:
          type: string
          pattern: '^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$'
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        responsibilities:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/EmployeeResponsibilities'
    ManagementInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          default: Bob
        title:
          type: string
          default: Manager
        responsibilities:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ManagerResponsibilities'
    ManagerResponsibilities:
      description: manager responsibilities
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - Meetings
          - Sleeping
          - Planning
          - Rehersing
          - Supervising
      default:
        - meetings
        - sleeping
    EmployeeResponsibilities:
      title: Employee Responsibilities
      description: Employee responsibilities
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - cleaning
          - organizing
          - attending
      default:
        - cleaning
```

If you paste this example into the [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) you will see that the `EmployeeInfo` schema is a parent object to either `ManagementInfo` or `GruntInfo`.

[image: image of inheritance example]

This is how we can define polymorphic inheritance in our schema.

This will very conveniently generate into a model called `interface EmployeeInfo` and two child objects called `class ManagementInfo implements EmployeeInfo` and `class GruntInfo implements EmployeeInfo`.

*Note:  I'm assuming java here, but hopefully you get the general idea.*

So, as you can see, the generator config options have nothing to do with model generation.  This is based strictly upon your schema.

Comment: Currently, `EmployeeInfo` is an interface but it is only a "marker" interface with no properties. Is there a technique for establishing the actual properties in the interface, and the class simply implements the interface without redeclaring the same properties?